# Integrating postgresql with tableau

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

Unable to connect to the server when using connecting postgresql to tableau.

Tableau shows "Error code: BC42EF73. SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above. Unable to connect to the PostgreSQL server "localhost". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database."

i tried connecting postgresql with tableau. I am expecting connection of dvdrental database file of postgresql to tableau.

Comment: Are you using tableau desktop or server?  What version?  What OS (and version)?

Comment: I am using tableau desktop

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: If postgres 12 or 13, check the driver you are using in https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers

Download the jar file and copy it here: ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers

Option 2: If you don't need

scram-sha-256 authentication, you can revert to md5

set password_encryption = md5 in  postgresql.conf
change the authentication method to  md5 in  pg_hba_conf
reload PostgreSQL
change the password of the user to get an MD5-encrypted password

Just setup my own

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me "  how can i change the password of the user to get an MD5-encrypted password"